# How to change the default Image position in tab host : android

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-tabhost, android-imageview

I need to change the default position of image inside tab host , i want to display image as pointing image at the top of the each tab when we click on any tab ..so now how to change the default position of image in side the tab widget ?
my simple xml code for display tab widget is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate `tabwidget` to any view you want using [setIndicator (View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29)

```
public TabHost.TabSpec setIndicator (View view)
Since: API Level 4

Specify a view as the tab indicator.
```

Example:

**TabWidget layout:** `tab_widget_custom.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tabwidget_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabIndicatorIcon"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabIndicatorText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In activity create a method return `tabwidget` view

```
private View getTabIndicatorView(Context context, String tag, int drawable) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.tab_widget_custom, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabIndicatorText);
        tv.setText(tag);
        ImageView tabIndicatorIcon = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tabIndicatorIcon);
        tabIndicatorIcon.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
        return view;

    }
```

Use this method to create new `tabwidget`

```
private void initTab() {
        Intent intent;
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Inbox").setIndicator(
                getTabIndicatorView(MainTabActivity.this, "Inbox",
                        R.drawable.inbox_tab_selector));

        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        }
```